# A PostreSQL "interval "does not complie

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following condition in a Postgres query:

```
…where (o.estimate_close_date + m.MonthNumber) < (o.estimate_close_date + **interval** '1 month' * o.duration_months)…
```

This test is compiled OK while it is just an SQL text.
But when a put this on a VIEW I get the following compilation error:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "months"
> Position: 171

What it is ? I fin the root case is the "interval"
; but whet exactly to do with it?

Comment: Could you post the SQL for the view?

Comment: The problem seems to be in the parts you didn't show us.